# Does build/index.html serve as a standalone webpage without server?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app

Does build/index.html generated after npm run build serve as a standalone webpage or does it only work with serve -s build.

index.html file returns blank page and on inspecting the page it shows: **"main.17cbfec0.js:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND"**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should serve the entire `build` directory, not just specific files as the `index.html` file relies on various JavaScript bundles generated by CRA, which are all located in that `build` folder.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. So, will index.html file render the entire app as it gets rendered in npm start server or serve -s build, from the <project-directory>/build location itself, without any local server.

Comment: it's true that you can open the index.html file without a local server, but it's generally recommended to always use a local server, since a) it will be the closest to the environment you're deploying the application in and b) it fixes lots of weird file path quirks and generally makes life a lot more easier.

Comment: The index.html file in project-path/build location is returning a blank page. Why does this happen?

Comment: this issue you're facing is a prime example of the path quirks that come with not using a local server. in index.html, it's importing `/main.17cbfec0.js`, but since you're not using a server, it's looking in the root directory of your computer for it, where it isn't. try using a local server and try again.